# JackRabbit: textFilterClasses deprecated. How to specify extractors?

Tags: lucene, jackrabbit, jcr

My **Jackrabbit 2.4** says, that **textFilterClasses** parameter of **SearchIndex** element is deprecated and ignored. When I remove the **textFilterClasses** parameter all together, it indexes Pdf, Rtf - everything.

How does it know, what binary files it should index, when I'm not specifying no extractors?

API says it's deprecated, but doesn't provide any alternative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jackrabbit 2.x Apache Tika was introduced as the default binaries parser. By default Jackrabbit comes with a default tika-config.xml file that contains the configuration for which mime-types to parse and extract.

In Jackrabbit 2.4 you should be able to set the location of the tika-config.xml from within the repository.xml.

The correct parameter inside your search index configuration should be something similar to:

```
<SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
  <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
  <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
  <param name="tikaConfigPath" value="${wsp.home}/tika-config.xml"/>
</SearchIndex>
```